# Creating Windows Form outside of Application.Run results in strange behaviour. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, unity-game-engine, invoke

After a week of code-debugging I found that the problem my Windows-Forms based GUI was behaving strangely was because I was running the form as:

```
Form1 myGui = new Form1();
Application.Run(myGui);
```

changing the code to:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

apparently did the trick.

The problem i had was that, for some reason, if I created the form in the first way and tried to marshal a call with the Invoke/BeginInvoke pattern, the call was never resolved, leaving the other thread hanging in the case of Invoke, or simply never calling the function with BeginInvoke.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Moreover, I'm running the application over Mono and Unity3D.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Is it a scoping issue?  There is no difference between the 2 methods except for the lifetime of Form1.

Comment: The two lines of code do exactly the samething. This sounds like a problem with Mono.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. 

As for the scoping, the variable "myGui" is a class variable that gets instantiated when the class constructor is called, but gets run when the method "SpawnGui" is called. I do no think this may cause scoping issues!

As of mono, yeah, that might be the problem, but this behavior is so strange that i thought there was some other problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with many scenarios under Windows and Mono where form references are managed either globally or scoped to classes that are available during a static call to Application.Run in or via the Main method. This sounds too suspicious to be anything but a scoping issue. Have you tried a minimalist app with only the piece of code you mention? I could not reproduce the same results using Unity3D under Mono.